# Adapter Design Pattern- Relationship Types Between Roles

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter, aggregation, ooad

I'm interested to know about the relationships (Aggregation, Composition) between the different roles of adapter design pattern. I still have few confusions over association and aggregation. I have posted the class diagram of Adapter below. I need to know whether adaptee is in an aggregation relationship with adapter.

[image: Adapter Design Pattern UML]

Aggregation relationship is defined as shown in the below code snippet.I know that aggregation is not implied in the UML but I see that there is a similar implementation in the adapter and adaptee as shown in the below code.

```
final class Car {

  private Engine engine;

  void setEngine(Engine engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
  }

  void move() {
    if (engine != null)
      engine.work();
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain me, why the relationship between adapter and adapteee doesn't fall into the category of Aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

> Aggregation is a part-of relationship.
>   .
>   .
>
> In the pre-UML days, people were usually rather vague on what was
>   aggregation and what was association. Whether vague or not, they were
>   always inconsistent with everyone else. As a result, many modelers
>   think that aggregation is important, although for different reasons.
>   So the UML included aggregation but with hardly any semantics. As Jim
>   Rumbaugh says, "Think of it as a modeling placebo"

Quoted from [UML Distilled: A Brief Guide to the Standard Object Modeling Language, Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687).

So according to the definition, the adapter may not aggregate the adaptee. In other words the adaptee may not be in a part-of relationship with the adapter.

Another thing is the fact that aggregation has no semantics what so ever so using it has become more or less of a personal choice.

One last thing. I always felt kind of vagueness about the difference between association, aggregation and composition but after reading DDD by Eric Evans i had another prespective about it so i wrote an article about the subject. If you care to take a look at [Relationships in Context](http://snifferjr.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/relations-put-into-context/).